# MPAndroidChart Scrubbing?

Tags: android, graph, mpandroidchart

I know there are interaction listeners such as onChartGestureStart, onChartSingleTapped, etc.

What I would like to have is kind of what spark has which is scrubbing for a line chart. So when you drag your finger over the points of the chart, I can get the Y values and update a TextView.

Currently, if you use either onChartGestureStart or onChartSingleTapped, the values updates only once where you originally tap and if you tap again, it'll update.

Is there a hack around to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setHighlightEnabled(true)` to enable the scrubbing, and listen to value selected via `OnChartValueSelectedListener`.

See wiki [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Highlighting).